# GameMaker calculate the Object's speed with xprevious and yprevious?

Tags: game-maker, gml

Can't calculate speed based on that.

I'm using paths to move objects so built in direction is speed is always zero?

How can I calculate the real speed of the object?

No matter what xprevious is always x and y previous is always y.

Answer (score 1):

The speed that you've originally set an object to follow a path with can be found in `path_speed` variable, but for paths with varying per-point speeds you can calculate it yourself by checking distance in an **End Step** event:

```
spd = point_distance(xprevious, yprevious, x, y);
```

[image]